# Get path of exact dependency from node_modules package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

How can I get path of exact dependency from a certain `node_modules` package?

For example:

```
|- node_modules/
   |- package-a@2.1.0/
      |- package.json
   |- package-b/
      |- node_modules/
         |- package-a@1.0.0/
      |- package.json
   |- package-c/
      |- package.json
```

Is there a way I can get the location of `package-a` that `package-b` depends on only by reading `node_modules/package-b/package.json`? In this case, the output should be `node_modules/package-b/node_modules/package-a/package.json`. While for `package-c`, it should be `node_modules/package-a/package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement the same resolution mechanism as used by Node itself:

1. Change the current directory to `./node_modules/package-b`
2. If there is a folder `node_modules` - check whether there is `node_modules/package-a` subfolder
3. If there is such a folder - return its full path
4. If there is no such folder - if the current directory is `/` (root) then exit otherwise change the current directory to `../` and go to step (2)